# Are these lines in the magic tag wiki necessary?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-wiki

An excerpt from the [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) [tag wiki](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/magic/info) includes the following:

> Usually it is a power that normal people don't have, and is wielded instead by a special caste (wizards, sorcerers, witches, mages, etc.)

While this is true for many examples, a significant number of [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) questions describe the popular, widespread use of magic in society.

This line may accurately describe *some* [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) questions, but it doesn't contribute much - the rest of the wiki pretty much says it all -

> Magic or sorcery is an attempt to understand and exploit supernatural forces, using rituals, symbols, actions, gestures and language...

and it may alienate other questions.

**Is there a good reason to keep this line of the wiki?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, the first sentence isn't really needed. However it does include the word "usually" and it is true that most fantasy scenarios usually involve a special caste of magic using individuals.

So I'm ambivalent about it. I don't mind the sentence being there, but also don't object to it being deleted.